# How to display image width and height in FEH?

Tags: linux, feh

I want FEH to display image's width and height in bottom-left corner (like: 1920x1080)

But

```
feh --info "%wx%h"
```

doesn't work, and terminal says:

```
sh: 1: 1920x1080: not found
```

Comment: the feh man page says that the format is `feh --info command` ... try `feh --info "echo %wx%h"`

Comment: @jsotola: that works for me. You should turn that into an answer, so it can be properly upvoted and accepted

Answer (score 3):

The feh man page says that the format is

```
feh --info command
```

Try

```
feh --info "echo %wx%h"
```

https://manpages.org/feh